# How to run gsettings or "nohup nm-applet &" as normal user in a script started with sudo?

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, gnome, sudo

I wrote some scripts that have commands such as:

```
gsettings ...
nohup nm-applet &
```

Both commands showed feedback when running the script without sudo (as normal user).

When I started the script using sudo, the script successfully ran, but those commands didn't show any feedback.

Running the script with sudo using commands like these doesn't work even when `whoami` already shows normaluser. Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
exitfn() {
#try1
nohup nm-applet &
#try2
sudo -i -u normaluser bash <<EOF
whoami
nohup nm-applet &
EOF
#try3
su - normaluser -c "whoami && nohup nm-applet &"
}

trap "exitfn" INT
sudo killall nm-applet
sleep 3600
trap SIGINT
```

In the end I opted to separate the script parts into normaluser part and a part where sudo is needed, but I am still wondering why this is the case.
Is there a way to get these two commands running in a script called with sudo?

**UPDATE**

**gsettings** :

It turns out that I need to add `gsettings --schemadir`
since the extension I installed is only in the home dir; not in the root.

Add `sudo -E` as suggested by @meuh

**nm-applet**:

With `sudo`, it actually ran, but did not show on the desktop notifbar.
Without `sudo`, it ran **and** showed on the desktop notifbar.

Comment: gsettings needs a dbus, and sudo is dropping the variable DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS from the env.  You need to preserve it.

Comment: @meuh does this apply to nm-applet as well?

Comment: @meuh I have been looking online about but didnt really understand how to apply that to my script. How can I do that?

Comment: Use the `env` command to see what variables it lists before using sudo. Try running the script with `sudo -E` to preserve these variables.